# LangChain: Reduce size of tokens being passed to OpenAI

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, deeplake, activeloop

I am using LangChain to create embeddings and then ask a question to those embeddings like so:

```py
embeddings: OpenAIEmbeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(disallowed_special=())
db = DeepLake(
    dataset_path=deeplake_url,
    read_only=True,
    embedding_function=embeddings,
)
retriever: VectorStoreRetriever = db.as_retriever()
model = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo") 
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(model, retriever=retriever)
result = qa({"question": question, "chat_history": chat_history})
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
File "/xxxxx/openai/api_requestor.py", line 763, in _interpret_response_line
    raise self.handle_error_response(
openai.error.InvalidRequestError: This model's maximum context length is 4097 tokens. However, your messages resulted in 13918 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages.
```

The chat_history is empty and the question is quite small.

How can I reduce the size of tokens being passed to OpenAI?

I'm assuming the response from the embeddings is too large being passed to openai. It might be easy enough to just figure out how to truncate the data being sent to openai.

Comment: This implies that either the documents you want to query or the chat history is too long. Can you show how long the chat history is, and use `return_source_documents` to show how long those are? https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/chains/index_examples/chat_vector_db.html#return-source-documents

Comment: chat history is empty, and the question is quite short. I'll update the question. I'm assuming the embeddings it is passing to openai are too big, but not sure how to see them and manually truncate them.

Comment: Langchain is not passing embeddings to your language model. It is passing the documents associated with each embedding, which are text. Although the embeddings are a fixed size, the documents could potentially be any size, depending on how you split your documents. (Or if you split them at all.)

Comment: Right, the text associated with the embeddings that we are passing is too big. It probably would be easiest if I could find out where those are being passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary

When you initiate the `ConversationalRetrievalChain` object, pass in a `max_tokens_limit` amount.

```py
qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
        model, retriever=retriever, max_tokens_limit=4000
    )
```

This will automatically truncate the tokens when asking openai / your llm.

## Longer explainer

In the `base.py` of `ConversationalRetrievalChain` there is a function that is called when asking your question to deeplake/openai:

```py
    def _get_docs(self, question: str, inputs: Dict[str, Any]) -> List[Document]:
        docs = self.retriever.get_relevant_documents(question)
        return self._reduce_tokens_below_limit(docs)
```

Which reads from the `deeplake` vector database, and adds that as context to your doc's text that you upload to openai.

The `_reduce_tokens_below_limit` reads from the class instance variable `max_tokens_limit` to truncate the size of the input docs.

Comment: I am also getting the same error, my chunk size is 300, have around 400K chunks, chormadb and am using RetrievalQA. Can you please tell me where in code can I add max_tokens_limit?

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, the current explanation is not strictly true, it might just be working by accident.

max_tokens_limit applies specifically to the new tokens created by the model.

However, the limit of a model in tokens, is the sum of all tokens input and generated by the model. So if you happen to reduce the new tokens by enough you can clear the overall bar set by the model. However, it's feasible to still exceed the model's limit even if you set the max_tokens_limit = 0, if your input tokens are too great.

Your input tokens + max_tokens_limit <= model token limit.

Everyone will have a different approach, depending on which they prefer to prioritize. For example, if I'm using a 512 token model, I might aim for a max token output of around 200 token, so I will clip the input token length to 312.

This will completely depend on your model, task type, and use-case.

EDIT: if you use tokenizer directly, which doesn't seem to the be case, you can add a max_length limit to the tokenised input_ids. But I don't think this happens with Langchain - it's handled by the pipeline/chain.